# Print values of array of arrays in flask

Tags: python, flask

I have this array of arrays:

```
[['Frutta', 
['M01', '2018-08-06 08:35:00', '2018-08-06 10:13:00'], ['M02', 
'2018-08-06 10:18:00', '2018-08-06 11:42:00'], ['M04', '2018-08-06 15:19:00', 
'2018-08-06 16:37:00']], 

['verdura', 
['M01', '2018-08-06 08:35:00', '2018-08-06 10:25:00']]]
```

and I want to print each field

so, with flask I tried like this:

```
{% for prodotto in range(inserisci_ordine[1]| length) %}
{{ inserisci_ordine[prodotto][0] }}<br>
{% for macchine in range(inserisci_ordine[prodotto]| length) %}
{{ inserisci_ordine[prodotto][macchine] }}<br>
{{ inserisci_ordine[prodotto][macchine][2] }}<br>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I would like to print something like this:

`frutta`

- `M01, 2018-08-06 08:35:00, 2018-08-06 10:13:00`
- `M02, 2018-08-06 10:18:00, 2018-08-06 11:42:00`
- `M04, 2018-08-06 15:19:00, 2018-08-06 16:37:00`

`verdura`

- `M01, 2018-08-06 08:35:00, 2018-08-06 10:25:00`

But I can't figure it out..

---

EDIT.

Is it possible in some way, print also the machine utilized in the previous cycle? for example:

`frutta`

- `M01, 2018-08-06 08:35:00, 2018-08-06 10:13:00` #I want to print here `, NULL`
- `M02, 2018-08-06 10:18:00, 2018-08-06 11:42:00` #Here the `, M01`
- `M04, 2018-08-06 15:19:00, 2018-08-06 16:37:00` #here the `, M02`

`verdura`

- `M01, 2018-08-06 08:35:00, 2018-08-06 10:25:00` #here `, NULL`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

base.html

```
{% for row in data %}
    {{row[0]}}
    <ul>
        {% for element in row[1:] %}
            <li>{{element|join(', ')}}<li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

## view.py

```
@app.route('/')
def sample_view():
    data = [
        [
            'Frutta', 
            ['M01', '2018-08-06 08:35:00', '2018-08-06 10:13:00'], 
            ['M02', '2018-08-06 10:18:00', '2018-08-06 11:42:00'],
            ['M04', '2018-08-06 15:19:00', '2018-08-06 16:37:00']
         ], 
        ['verdura', ['M01', '2018-08-06 08:35:00', '2018-08-06 10:25:00']]
    ]

    return render_template("base.html", data=data)
```

Comment: Your solution is fantastic, just one more question, how can I print in the template the machine utilized in the previous cycle? I'll do an example in the question. thankyou

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll have an easier time if you add an extra level of nesting to each group. So that the array of arrays is actually list of `[[name, list_of_machines], [name, list_of_machines], ...]`. If you do that, you can create a loop that creates a table for each headline using the following template:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, BaseLoader

template_string = """
{% for group_index in range(arrays| length) %}
    <h3>{{ arrays[group_index][0] }}</h3>
    <table>
        {% for machine in range(arrays[group_index][1] | length) %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ arrays[group_index][1][machine][0] }}</td>
                <td>{{ arrays[group_index][1][machine][1] }}</td>
                <td>{{ arrays[group_index][1][machine][2] }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </table>
{% endfor %}

"""


data = [
['Frutta',
 [['M01', '2018-08-06 08:35:00', '2018-08-06 10:13:00'],
  ['M02', '2018-08-06 10:18:00', '2018-08-06 11:42:00'],
  ['M04', '2018-08-06 15:19:00', '2018-08-06 16:37:00']]],

['verdura',
[['M01', '2018-08-06 08:35:00', '2018-08-06 10:25:00']]]]

template = Environment(loader=BaseLoader).from_string(template_string)
print(template.render(arrays=data))
```